# How to replace a value in multiple columns based on criteria?

Tags: r, replace, find, criteria

I would like to replace all values `99` with `NA` for all records where `ART == '999'` only in columns `L1:L8`. I know how to do this for once column at a time, but I would like to do this more efficiently for all columns in one command.

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(KARTA = c("02C2H", "02C2H", "02C2H", "02C2H", 
"02C2H", "02C2H", "02C2H", "02C2H", "02C2H", "02C2H", "02C2H", 
"02C2H", "02C2H", "02C7H", "02C7H", "02C7H", "02C7H", "02C7H", 
"02C7H", "02C7H", "02C7H", "02C7H", "02C7H", "02C7H", "02C7H"
), YEAR = c(1997L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 1997L, 1998L, 2000L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2006L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L
), ART = c("999", "999", "100", "100", "100", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999"), L1 = c(99, 
99, 99, 99, 99, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
99, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), L2 = c(99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 10, 9, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10), L3 = c(99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), L4 = c(99, 
99, 99, 99, 99, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
99, 10, 10, 8, 7, 7, 10, 8), L5 = c(99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 5, 8, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 99, NA, 99, 99, 99, 10, 10, 7, 7, 0, 
10, 8), L6 = c(99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 10, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), L7 = c(99, 
99, 99, 99, 99, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 10, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
99, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), L8 = c(99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 10, 10, 6, 10, 
10, 10, 10)), .Names = c("KARTA", "YEAR", "ART", "L1", "L2", 
"L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8"), row.names = c(161008L, 161009L, 
161010L, 161011L, 161012L, 87055L, 106223L, 128072L, 160909L, 
172583L, 208774L, 45L, 227972L, 161013L, 161014L, 161015L, 161016L, 
161017L, 71813L, 89034L, 139633L, 181266L, 208838L, 97L, 225989L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Example of how to replace values in a single column ('L1')

```
df[which(df$ART == '999' & df$L1 == '99'), ] <- NA
```

Comment: You were close. `df[df == 999 | df == 99] <- NA` (notice no comma).

Comment: and notice the or (`|`) instead of `&`.

Comment: I am closer, but when I use your code then '999' in the column 'ART' is also replaced by 'NA'. I want to replace only the fields 'L1:L8'.

Comment: you couldn't figure it out? pretty easy to infer, isn't it? `df[df==99] <- NA`

Comment: yes, but my sample data only includes records where ART == 999. I want a criteria that limits the replacement of '99' with 'NA' to only those records. I am updating the sample data to make it more clear.

Comment: there's no ART in the data anymore?

Comment: Sorry I just fixed it!

Comment: But @Arun's command should still work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example data `ART` is always 999, but I assume that is not always case and you want to replace `99` with `NA` in only those rows where `ART==999`, that could be done like this:

```
df$ART[3:5]<-100 #just to give some difference
df[df$ART==999, 4:10][df[df$ART==999,4:10] == 99] <- NA

       KARTA YEAR ART L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 L6 L7 L8
161008 02C2H 1997 999 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 99
161009 02C2H 1999 999 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 99
161010 02C2H 2000 100 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
161011 02C2H 2001 100 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
161012 02C2H 2002 100 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
87055  02C2H 2003 999 10 10  7 10  5  8 10 10
...
```

Comment: I edited the dataset in my question to make sure there was more than one value for the field 'ART'. Thanks for your help!